# mouse selection memory messed up ctrl-c after pacman -Syu

Tags: archlinux

I am using Endea Linux, just did twice in recent few days "pacman -Syu"

Just now i realized; the content of ctrl-c being over written by mouse selection.

Now, whatever i select / highlight with mouse, i can paste it with ctl-v.. no longer need middle mouse button.. this is messed up.

After this messed up, i can't use ctrl-c anymore.. because as long as i accidentally highlighted a character (hand glitch) , all my content in ctrl-c register is overwrittened, sick!

Anybody can help me solve this issue ?

Thx

Comment: Why did i get a -ve vote ? is it a stupid question to ask ?  I can't use Ctrl-c now because of this bug.. i need some input  to guide me fixing it, so i can use ctrl -c.. it is impossible to use copy and paste like this.

Comment: Don't edit "solved" into the title. The only acceptable way to mark something solved is to accept an answer using the checkbox next to an answer. If you need to (if nobody else's answer was acceptable), you can add your own answer and then accept it; there's a delay before the checkbox is available for self-answers, but it'll show up eventually.

Comment: BTW, I'm guessing the downvote is for the same reason as the close vote: Because this isn't on-topic here, not being specific to software development. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se] are more appropriate Stack Exchange sites for questions about using your Linux distro.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What is the topic for this stackexchage ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- this particular site is only for questions "*unique to software development*" (ANDed into the other conditions above it, so a question should have one of the first three bullet points apply, and also the fourth in addition; as well as _not_ having any of the items in the "some questions are still off-topic" list later on apply). If something is an issue folks could be expected to run into during general use of their system for non-programming purposes, it isn't unique to development.

Answer (score 0):

*click on clipboard content > configure clipboard > general configuration  > make sure both "ignore selection" and "Synchronize contents of the clipboard and the selection" options are set properly as default listed below.

### Ignore selection (default: on)

Sets the clipboard mode. This option will prevent Klipper from including the contents of the selection in its clipboard history and from performing actions on the contents of the selection. See the section called “Clipboard/Selection Behavior”.

### Synchronize contents of the clipboard and the selection (default: off)

Sets the clipboard mode. When an area of the screen is selected with mouse or keyboard, this is called the “selection”. If this option is selected, the selection and the clipboard is kept the same, so that anything in the selection is immediately available for pasting elsewhere using any method, including the traditional middle mouse button. Otherwise, the selection is recorded in the clipboard history, but the selection can only be pasted using the middle mouse button. Also see the Ignore selection option. See the section called “Clipboard/Selection Behavior”.

### *Changing Clipboard/Selection Behavior

- In order to change clipboard/selection behavior, select Configure Klipper... from the Klipper context menu, and in the dialog box that appears, select the General page.
  *Unchecking "Synchronize contents of the clipboard and the selection" makes the "clipboard" and "selection" function as completely separate buffers as described above.
  *With this option set, the option "Ignore selection" will prevent Klipper from including the contents of the "selection" in its clipboard.
- Selecting "Synchronize contents of the clipboard and the selection" causes the clipboard and selection buffers to always be the same, meaning that text in the selection can be pasted with either the middle mouse button or the key combination Ctrl+V, and similarly for text in the clipboard buffer.